# Are questions discussing printer construction, internals, and firmware on-topic here?

Tags: support, scope

Looking at the highly upvoted [area 51 questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82438/3d-printing?page=1&tab=votes&phase=definition#tab-top), we seem to have a lot of questions focusing on 3D printing from the viewpoint of someone producing items, but a dearth of those discussing actual printer construction, modification, and firmware configuration/creation/programming. Are such questions on-topic for this site's scope?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, I think such questions should be on-topic.

Comment: Agree.  I think at this stage of development, 3D printing experts are necessarily going to be asking and answering questions about printer internals nearly as much as using them, and, in fact, and lot of usage questions will rely on this specific internal expertise.

Comment: I agree also, but what types of questions 3D printing related would be considered off topic?

Comment: @ChaseCromwell That seems like a [separate question](http://meta.3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/21/are-questions-that-tangentially-involve-3d-printing-on-topic).

Comment: Also agreed, strongly.