# Repairing 3D printer

Tags: discussion, support, scope, asking-questions

The end switches of my 3D spider printer don't work well. I wonder whether it's on-topic asking how to repair 3D printers. In my case I'd describe what does not work, what the result is and what parts are used.

From a good answer I'd expect a proposal on how to fix it, e.g. a suggestion for an electronic piece to buy (like a photo sensor maybe) and how to apply the wiring etc.

Derived from [Printer construction](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/are-questions-discussing-printer-construction-internals-and-firmware-on-topic), I'd also say that repairing must be on-topic.

Comment: This should really be carrying the [discussion] and [scope] tags :)

Comment: @Zizouz212: added them. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that repair questions are more on-topic than construction. And if construction questions are okay, then repair questions should be too.

An example format might be:

## How do I repair {X}

> I've tried {a[]} to fix {X}, but {b[]} occurred. What are some other common means of fixing {X}?

Most of what is acceptable on SE is troubleshooting and I feel that repairing is a subset of troubleshooting. In other words, typically you'll result in repairing from troubleshooting, but [hopefully] not the other way around. So, a repair question is essentially requiring, upfront, what a great quality answer would provide in some troubleshooting questions.

For example:

## {X} wont work

> {X} isn't working, what could be the cause?

could lead to:

> I've encountered {X} as a result of {Y}. I was able to fix it by performing {C}.

Where **{C}** is typically going above and beyond the OP's question.

Comment: I agree that should be in scope. It's certainly an area where people in our target audience (including myself) need help, and diagnosis can get tricky at times.

Comment: @TextGeek I've now added the subject to the list of [appropriate topics](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)